# How to run a chef recipe after vagrant box provisioned

Tags: chef-infra, vagrant, berkshelf

I'm using Vagrant + Berkshelf + Chef Solo to mirror behavior of my production AWS OpsWorks boxes on my development machine.

I can get the vagrant box up just fine, but now, after it has been provisioned, I want to be able to run a different Chef recipe from the cookbooks used during provisioning.  I want to do this because I'm trying to emulate OpsWorks' behavior: they let me run a `deploy` recipe with the push of a button.  I want to be able to either use vagrant or chef-solo inside my vagrant box to run that same recipe.

I think I can solve this by adding a recipe to the provisioning process that builds up different `solo.rb` config files for the different on-demand recipes I want to run.  These config files would point to the Vagrant/Berkshelf `cookbooks_path` (which is `/tmp/vagrant-chef-1/` for me) and then set the run list to the appropriate recipe.  These config files would then be used by chef-solo.

I get the feeling that someone has solved this problem before in a more elegant way.  Is there a better way to do this?

If not, does anyone know a way from within Vagrant or within a recipe to find the cookbook path so I don't have to hardcode `/tmp/vagrant-chef-1/` into my `solo.rb` config files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add [multiple provisioners](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/basic_usage.html). So after your first `config.vm.provision :chef_solo` block just add another one applying the recipe you want to run after the first deployment.

Comment: But can I add multiple `:chef_solo` provisioners and then target them individually?  My impression is that you can only specify the type of the provisioner to run, but not specify the ID of one to run.

Comment: Umm.. why don't you just give it a try? It works for me (in the current vagrant version) to add two `chef.vm.provision :chef_solo` blocks.

Comment: Right, but can you call vagrant such that only one of them runs? (i.e. "Vagrant please run the 2nd `:chef_solo` block")

Comment: Do you want to skip the first provisioning only because it takes some time? Provisioning is idempotent, so it doesn't change anything, if you run it multiple times.

Comment: Nevertheless, you can surround the `provision` blocks with arbitrary ruby code. So surround it e.g. with `if ENV['FOO'] ... end` will execute the provisioning code only when you've exported the environment variable `FOO` before (to sth. treated as non-false).

Comment: Re "Do you want..." it is more that I don't want to run the second provisioning (the "AWS deploy" provisioning) when I run the first one (the "AWS setup-the-machine provisioning").

Comment: Re your second point (the environment variable approach), that's a good idea :-).  Haven't tested it but I'm sure it would work and will accept that as the answer.  FWIW, what I ended up doing was writing a LWRP to dump out a script that calls chef-solo with the appropriate configuration from within the VM.  Wish I were getting SO notifications better and had seen your comment earlier :-)

Comment: Ended up adding adding a quickie vagrant plugin inline in the Vagrantfile so I could say `vagrant deploy` (https://gist.github.com/jpslav/5629662)

Answer (score 0):

Actual chef-solo configuration and attributes are stored in `/tmp/vagrant-chef/solo.rb` and `/tmp/vagrant-chef/dna.json` files within your vagrant box.

Executing the full chef provisioning:

`sudo chef-solo -c /tmp/vagrant-chef/solo.rb -j /tmp/vagrant-chef/dna.json`

Overriding the defined run list and running just a single recipe (e.g. memcached):

`sudo chef-solo -c /tmp/vagrant-chef/solo.rb -j /tmp/vagrant-chef/dna.json -o recipe[memcached]`